# How to optimize this query?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have tables:
A (ID_A, VALID_FROM, DATA ...)
B (ID_B, ID, T1, T2, T3, DATE)

Table A can contain historical data (eg. data valid for given period)
I need to select records from table B joined with appropritate records from table A (from table A I need row where b.id = a.id_a and record was valid at b.date)

```
select * 
from B, (select * from (select * from A where a.id_a = b.id and a.valid_from <= b.date order by valid_from desc) where rownum = 1)
where b.id = a.id_a
```

Comment: What indexes do you have and what are the explain plan results? Performance tuning in a database should start there, not re-writing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much more optimal, but is probably more readable:

```
select *  
from A a, B b
Where 
a.id_a = b.id 
and a.valid_from = (select max(valid_from) 
                    from A 
                    where id_a = b.id 
                    and valid_from <= b.date)
order by valid_from desc
```

I've seen this problem before, and the best way I know of to optimise it is to put a valid_to column onto table A.

For the latest record, this should contain the biggest date Oracle can handle.
Whenever you create a newer version of the record, update it with the time the new record is created (minus a millisecond to avoid overlaps) so you have something like this:

```
ID Valid_from                Valid_to
1  01/01/2011 12.34.56.0000  02/01/2011 12.34.56.0000
1  02/01/2011 12.34.56.0001  03/01/2011 12.34.56.0000
1  03/01/2011 12.34.56.0001  31/12/9999 23.59.59.9999
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
select *  
from A a, B b
Where 
a.id_a = b.id 
and b.date between a.valid_from and a.valid_to
order by valid_from desc
```

With an index on the date columns, the performance should be ok..

Comment: Thanks. Query with valid_from = max() is quite slower on Oracle. When you put column ValidTo inside table you get slower insert/update - because you have to find previous history record and update it and insert new one. There is additional select and update. But it is probably the best solution :(

Comment: Agree, it is a bit slower. If insert/update performance is an issue for you as well you could do what I do - store the non-latest versions in a seperate (history) schema. When you create a new version, rather than inserting, you update the current record inthe main schema, and trigger an insert of a copy of the old record into your history schema. 2 inserts is faster than a lookup + update + insert...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a JOIN: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Comment: perhaps an oracle reference might be more appropriate? :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly I am not sure if your url helps me. Problem is not how to write JOIN, but how to effective select particular record from table with history. Every record contain some data and validity field - ValidFrom. If you want to select particular record for given date, you have to select all records where ValidFrom <= :ParticulaDate. You get 0..* records where the record with minimal date is the right. So you have to do outer select to select that one.

Comment: Can you give us some example data so we can get a more solid idea of what you're trying to do? As I understand it, when you get a row from B, you have to get all the rows with 'smaller' dates from A, where the IDs match?

Comment: Table A (ID, DATA, ValidFrom): (1,'XXX1','01/01/2009') (1,'XXX2,'05/30/2009') (1,'XXX3,'01/11/2010') (2,'YYY,'01/01/1999'). Table B (ID, ID_A, DATE): (1,1,'02/01/2009') (2,2,'09/12/2011') (3,1,'06/30/2009). I want to get 1,1,'02/01/2009','XXX1'; 2,2,'09/12/2011','YYY'; 3,1,'06/30/2009','XXX2'

Comment: Not all records from A .. i need only one (or zero) records from A where IDs match and record from A is valid for B.date - Table A contains history. With every change of data in table A is created new record and ValidFrom is set to curren_timestamp. I need select record from A which was valid at given B.DATE

Answer (score 0):

I've taken StevieG's answer and expanded on it. Without a `valid_to` column there are tricky subqueries to write. I would propose using the `LEAD` analytic function to find the end of the current validity period and work with that. This is an alternative to the subqueries and the valid_to column.

The `LEAD` analytic function looks over the rows in the current data set and finds the next valid_from date and uses that as the end of the current period.

My query is shown below. It incorporates the sample data you provided, in a with clause.

```
with table_a as (
  select 1 as id, 'XXX1' as data, date '2009-01-01' as valid_from from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'XXX2' as data, date '2009-05-30' as valid_from from dual union all
  select 1 as id, 'XXX3' as data, date '2010-01-11' as valid_from from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'YYY' as data, date '1999-01-01' as valid_from from dual
),
table_b as (
  select 1 as id, 1 as id_a, date '2009-02-01' as date_col from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 2 as id_a, date '2009-09-12' as date_col from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 1 as id_a, date '2009-06-30' as date_col from dual
)
select *
from table_b b
  join (
    select 
      id, 
      valid_from, 
      lead(valid_from, 1, date '9999-12-31') over (partition by a.id order by a.valid_from) as valid_to
    from table_a a
) a on (a.id = b.id_a)
where 
  a.valid_from <= b.date_col and 
  b.date_col < a.valid_to
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works quite fine. Lead function requires Enterprise edition of Oracle database...